# Wicket TextField - Adding Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wicket

I am new to Wicket and encountering an issue while configuring a text field in wicket. I need to add some Javascript during this text field configuration so that i can convert it to Bootstrap Datepicker element (I have already used DateTimeField and DateTextField and they add calendar, hours and mins field which i don't want)

I have tried below code -

**HTML**

```
<div class="input">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input wicket:id="dateValue" class="std" style="color: black;" type="text" value="Date value" />
        <span class="input-group-addon dateTimePick"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Java**

```
private TextField<String> addValueDatePickerNew(final MarkupContainer parent, final String id, final IModel<String> model)
{
    final TextField<String> result = new TextField<String>(id, model) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onConfigure()
        {
            setVisibilityAllowed(true);
            setRequired(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) 
        {
            super.onComponentTag(tag);
            String jsDateField = "{console.log('From ReportFilterValueEditor');}";
            tag.put("onload", jsDateField);
        }
    };

    result.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    parent.add(result);
    return result;
}
```

Above code works and adds the JS statement during onload, however, looking for another way to add Javascript so that i can execute more lines of JS to achieve the functionality i need.

Comment: Wicket has a support for resource loading (css, js,...). The core element is method Component.renderHead.  You might find useful this part of the urser guide:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_adding_resources_to_page_header_section

Comment: Thq @Andrea Del Bene. resource loading i have done using the method mentioned in the link provided by you. I am looking for adding custom javascript like AppendJavaScript() method which is available for AjaxRequestEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
 @Override void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("some valid JavaScript Here"));
 }
```

You can also use `OnLoadHeaderItem` or `OnEventHeaderItem` if you think they are better for your use case.

Comment: Thank you @martin-g. I have used 

response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript(<some javascript here>); as onDomReadyHeaderItem was not working.

Comment: I am marking your answer as accepted as it is close in fixing my solution and believe works good for others too.

Comment: It seems you use a version older than 6.0.0, that's why the API looks different. I recommend you to upgrade to a version that is maintained!